# Step In with native code leads to garbage in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I have native code I've built using Gradle in Android Studio. Most of the debugging seems to work fine in C++, but I just added a new class and when I try to step in to the function call it takes me to an absolutely bizarre location in a completely unrelated area of code.

For example, I have the following line of code with a breakpoint:

`SemVer ver_cl = PlatformHelper::getAppVersion();`

I run "Step In", and I end up in `gnu-libstdc++` implementation of hashtable.h on a seemingly-arbitrary line of code.

I'm running in a simulator. I've made sure to sync my project to the Gradle files, but I'm not sure what could be causing this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of `PlatformHelper::getAppVersion();` can give insight to the problem. In this particular case it occurred that the method had no return value. For [historical reasons](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-I-receive-a-compile-error-when-I-dont-return-a-value-from-int-main), it is not an error in C++, but modern compilers usually trigger a warning in such situations and by adding `-Werror` compilation flag for GCC you can force it to treat warnings as errors. When non-void method does not return a value, the stack gets corrupted and control is returned to a random place. aardvarkk was "lucky" that the address occurred to be a valid one.

Another situation when similar behaviour can be seen is when when you compile your code with optimization (anything other then -O0). One of the strongest optimization techniques is inlining: function bodies are inserted directly in-to the place where they are called. This works especially good for templates. Downside of this process is that some functions are completely eliminated and they are not visible in stacktrace. So it is possible that when you step into `PlatformHelper::getAppVersion();` you directly drop somewhere in-to it's internals where hashmap is used because all the code between invocation of `getAppVersion` and usage of the hashmap has been optimized away. But in this case your program will function correctly, only debugging will be cumbered a bit.

Comment: I don't believe this is what's going on. The function body actually contains nothing right now -- just a line saying: `int n = 0;` so I could see if it landed inside of it. That being said, I'm now realizing I don't actually return a SemVer struct at the moment, and for some reason the compiler isn't complaining about that?! Seems weird...

Comment: Compiler indeed does not complain about not returning a value from function. And in such case when you return from function your stack is broken and things may go really weird.

Comment: Oh man -- it was totally just that I didn't return a valid value from the function. I'm used to that being a compiler error -- I didn't expect that kind of random behaviour. I'll upvote the answer. If you want to edit your answer so that it relates to the "actual" solution I'll also mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added the real problem to the answer. You can make compiler more picky about code quality by adding `-Wall` flag and also ask it to treat warnings as errors by `-Werror`. That's a really good choice for new code, but is a pain when warnings are caused by third party libraries you use.